# How to change text color for tab bar button in storyboard ios8

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitabbaritem

I changed tab bar background in Bar Tint field and want to change text colour for tab bar button. By default is grey and blue.
I try to change field Tint in section View, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *attribute = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]};
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attribute forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This will change the text colour for the tab bar button.

Answer (score 0):

This is for selected state:

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor]} forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

This is for not selected state:

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor greenColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: What place should i write it?

Comment: Where you setup your TabBarController, after instantiating it.

Answer (score 0):

**Try it**

To change tabbar text color you can use this

```
 [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary [UIColor redColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,[UIColor redColor],UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,[NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 0.5)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:10], UITextAttributeFont,nil]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```